# Do Loop in a Loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am facing problem doing loop in a loop. I don't know why loop in a loop is not running.

```
Program Console2
IMPLICIT NONE

Integer n,LineID,AA,AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF,GGG,J
Real :: A,B,C,D,S,BB,CC,DD
Character (LEN=10) Line,NodeID
OPEN(UNIT=2,FILE="Chaq.txt",STATUS='unknown')
OPEN(UNIT=12,FILE="CoOrd.txt",STATUS='unknown')
OPEN(UNIT=4,FILE="OUTPUT.txt",STATUS='unknown')


Do n=1,10
  Read (2,'(1x,a6,5x,i5,7x,i4,i8,i8,i8,i8)')NodeID,AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF

  write (4,*)NodeID,DDD

  Do J=1,10

    READ (12,('(1x,a4,7x,I5,8x,f8.2,f8.2,f8.2)'))Line,AA,BB,CC,DD

    write (4,*) Line,AA

  End Do

End Do

End  program Console2
```

Problem is for second loop it is not reading the values from second file: OUTPUT File:

```
 CQUAD4            5950
 GRID              3860
 GRID              3861
 GRID              3862
 GRID              3863
 GRID              3864
 GRID              3865
 GRID              3866
 GRID              3867
 GRID              3868
 GRID              3869
 CQUAD4            5949
```

Files Chaq.text: some lines

```
 CQUAD4      6817       2    6053    5950    5951    6054                   
 CQUAD4      6816       2    6052    5949    5950    6053                   
 CQUAD4      6815       2    6051    5948    5949    6052                   
 CQUAD4      6814       2    6050    5947    5948    6051            
 CQUAD4      6813       2    6192    5946    5947    6050
```

CoOrd.txt : Some Lines I shown

```
 GRID        3860        -171.90469.00543-28.5831                           
 GRID        3861        -186.50872.15994-28.5831                           
 GRID        3862        -180.23572.08246-28.5831                           
 GRID        3863        -184.573103.9741-28.5831                           
 GRID        3864        -171.92971.30236-28.5831                           
 GRID        3865        -191.05479.44247-28.5831                           
 GRID        3866        -159.938100.6297-28.5831                           
 GRID        3867        -169.58477.11039-28.5831                           
 GRID        3868        -176.62391.22597-28.5831                           
 GRID        3869        -185.83898.214  -28.5831
```

Comment: It is not obvious what do you mean by "it is not reading the values". What do you expect as desired output? Also would be nice to see at least few lines from both files Chaq.txt and CoOrd.txt.

Comment: BB, CC and DD are not defined in your code.?.. How it can work with IMPLICIT NONE?

Comment: sorry, while copying its mistake. Its Defined

Comment: well, isn't your CoOrd.txt file missing some whitespace between float numbers?

Comment: Thanks, yes its working, Problem is in looping ( loop in a loop) as i shown output.

Comment: What exactly the problem is? It crashes? Some runtine error?

Comment: I need repeat the same values of CoOrd.txt 10 values, For second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to read from the beginning of `CoOrd.txt` each time through the outer loop, then you need to rewind `CoOrd.txt` each time through the loop:

```
    Integer ReadStat
    ...

    Do n=1,10
      Read (2, '(1x,a6,5x,i5,7x,i4,i8,i8,i8,i8)', IOSTAT=ReadStat) NodeID,AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF
      If (ReadStat < 0) exit   ! EOF reached
      If (ReadStat > 0) stop   ! An unknown error occurred

      write (4,*)NodeID,DDD
      rewind(12)

      Do J=1,10
        READ (12, ('(1x,a4,7x,I5,8x,f8.2,f8.2,f8.2)', IOSTAT=ReadStat))Line,AA,BB,CC,DD

        If (ReadStat < 0) exit   ! EOF reached
        If (ReadStat > 0) stop   ! An unknown error occurred

        write (4,*) Line,AA

      End Do

    End Do
```

Comment: One more small query, If I have 950 lines in CoOrd.txt, For generally  loop If I do 'Do J=1,1000' why its gives run time error, How should I exactly fix run loop.

Comment: @ABOSs if you want your loop counter to be bigger than the file you're reading, you could add an argument to `read` to detect end of file and act accordingly. I updated the answer to show an example.